# I thought that this question is off-topic, but upon looking at the responses, I'm doubting myself

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, vote-to-close, off-topic

[image: off-topic?]

["Inline assembly" for Java byte codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040028/inline-assembly-for-java-byte-codes)

I'm now doubting myself, because at this point in time two people have responded and they both have over 100K reputation.  So that led me to think: "Well, if they both answered and didn't vote-to-close, then I'm probably incorrect."  Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: @Mat Thanks, I completely forgot to link the question.

Comment: @UphillLuge Can you please add an explanation as to why?  Not saying you're incorrect, but just saying that it's fine does not help me.  Perhaps you can explain via an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He was not actually asking for a library or tool, he want's to know if the concept is feasible.  With the assumption that, if it is feasible, that somebody might have used the approach in the past.

The question reads fine without that one line, deleting it doesn't alter the question.  So I just did.

Comment: Thanks for responding. So, since he gave specifics, this question would not be characterized as too broad? And as other suggested it shouldn't be migrated?

Comment: His request is *very* specific.  Generating machine code inline is a well-known technique in other languages.

Answer (score 5):

Close Reason:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library** or favorite
>   off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to
>   attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem
>   and what has been done so far to solve it.

Question:

> <strike>The question is: **do you know of any library/tool** that takes this
>   approach?</strike>

<strike>Seems to fit the bill to me.</strike>

**Update:**

> asking if something has been done is different from asking for the
>   best performance. – Shog9♦

It appears I stand corrected. I was mistaken and the question has since been edited to clear up the confusion. I retracted my close vote. Sorry about that.

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but both respondents have 100K+ rep, so I figured that I was missing something when they answered and didn't vote-to-close.

Comment: Except I'm not sure he's actually looking for a *recommendation*...

Comment: @Shog9 can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Shog9 Yeah, I can kind of see where you're coming from, but nonetheless I think that the question should at least be put on hold for him to clarify the meaning, then.

Comment: @apaul: asking if something has been done is different from asking for the best performance.